# Problems detecting swipe event after building up unordered list from Javascript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm building an unordered list dynamically from Javascript.  Everything has been fine.  List builds up, scrolls, I can select entries.  Now I'm trying to detect a swipe event.  If I add an li element in the HTML file, the swipe is detected.  If I add the same content from Javascript, the swipe is not detected.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML code

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:auto;max-height:450px;width:100%;" class="myScroller">
   <ol id="myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
      <li onclick="editHistoryItem('Sleep','146')"><div class="historyTitle"><img src="assets/sleep.png" class="historyImg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sleep</div></li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Code to detect swipe

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#home",function(){
     $("#myList li").on("swipeleft",function(){
         window.alert("hello there");
     });                       
});
```

Javascript code that builds list

```
$('#myList').append('<li onclick="editHistoryItem(\'' + entry[key][0] + '\',\'' + entry[key][11] + '\')"><div class="historyTitle"><img src="assets/sleep.png" class="historyImg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sleep</div></li>');
```

As I mentioned, the swipe event is not detected on the entries from Javascript but they are detected on the entries from the HTML file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

HTML code:

```
<ul id="myList"  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
</ul>
```

Javascript code (simplified) to build the list dynamically:

```
$('#myList').append('<li class="historyItem" id="sl' + entry[key][11] + '"><span class="historyTitle"><img src="assets/sleep.png" class="historyImg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + entry[key][0] + '</span></li>');
```

Javascript code to detect swipe:

```
$('#myList').on('swipeleft', 'li', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).closest('Li').attr('id');
    if (id !== undefined) {
        historyDeleteItem = id;
        historyDeleteThis = this;
        // do something here
    }
});
```

Hope it helps someone else!